# WSO2 User self registration

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to call the WSO2 Identity server web service using a java client.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserInformationRecoveryService service = new UserInformationRecoveryService();
    UserInformationRecoveryServicePortType port = service
            .getUserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint();

    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;

    prov.getRequestContext()
            .put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "admin");
    prov.getRequestContext()
            .put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "admin");

    try {

        List<UserIdentityClaimDTO> list = port
                .getUserIdentitySupportedClaims("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity");
        System.out.println(port
                .registerUser("user96", "Asdf@234", list, "profile", "")
                .getUserId().getValue());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I pass in password not matching the password criteria, I can see the error message in WSO2 logs:

> Password pattern policy violated. Password should contain a digit[0-9], a lower case letter[a-z], an upper case letter[A-Z], one of !@#$%&* characters

But when the password is compliant, I just get an error

> org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.services.UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceException_Exception: Error occurred while adding user : user96

Nothing in WSO2 log and the user is not added. Any clue as to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Better enable debug logs in the log configuration file.
[IS_Home]/repository/conf/log4j.properties
Add the following entry 
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG

This will give the debug logs which will help to understand the issue